# Gap between input and button

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

In an ASP.Net MVC application, I tried to use input-group for an input and button pair. I want it to look like this (like in getbootstrap.com):

[image]

But it looks like this in my application:
[image]

There is a huge space between input and button. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="input-group">
            <input id="empNoTxt" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Sicil Numarası" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Sorgula</button>
            </span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the solution from another site: 
https://jasenhk.wordpress.com/2014/06/09/mvc-bootstrap-input-group-button-space/

There is a default css file which is called "Site.css" in MVC projects. You should remove the following lines:

```
/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any thing wrong with your html... here is a working example of your code with the same button in three different container sizes.

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="empNoTxt" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Sicil Numarası" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Sorgula</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="empNoTxt" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Sicil Numarası" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Sorgula</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="empNoTxt" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Sicil Numarası" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Sorgula</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

make certain that your referencing the correct version of bootstrap.

Comment: Something is wrong with the version your using or you do not have a reference to bootstrap. What I posted for you is code that I literally use everyday in projects for clients. I would use the nuget package manager to update your bootstrap library first. If that does not work post your bundle.cs file and the head section of your layout page and I'll take a look at it...your html is correct the problem is somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<div class="input-group">

          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..."><span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
          </span>
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
```

Comment: can you reproduce the same in fiddle.